# Integration test for different instances of same application

Tags: java, docker, junit, testcontainers

I have a java application(no Spring). Replica of this application working at another server, with another instance of databse. Database table 'settings' have property master Y or N(for replica). After any action on master, i sending message to kafka an kafka sending action to replica with db update action. Any ideas for testing full cycle of this process?

I used testcontainers for getting kafka and databases. But i havent idea how to launch in testcontainer instance of my application with db.

Comment: What is actually running your tests? Could you `git clone` a certain version of it, then run the test scripts without needing containers of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is to [containerize](https://runnable.com/docker/java/dockerize-your-java-application) your java application. On each master action (merge), configure your CI/CD to create a docker image of your application. Then you can deploy your application using test containers.

```
GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer("myAppImage:release1")
        .withImagePullPolicy(PullPolicy.defaultPolicy());
```

Comment: That blog is one example, but [Dockerfiles aren't necessary to containerize a Java app](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib)